# spring cloud stream file source app - History of Processed files and polling files under sub directory

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I'm building a data pipeline with Spring Cloud Stream File Source app at the start of the pipeline. I need some help with working around some missing features

My File source app (based on org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-file) works perfectly well excepting missing features that I need help with. I need

1. To delete files after polled and messaged
2. Poll into the subdirectories

With respect to item 1, I read that the delete feature doesn't exist in the file source app (it is available on sftp source). Every time the app is restarted, the files that were processed in the past will be re-picked, can the history of files processed made permanent? Is there an easy alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support those requirements you definitely need to modify the code of the mentioned File Source project: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Einstein.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications

I would suggest to fork the project and poll it from GitHub as is, since you are going to modify existing code of the project. Then you follow instruction in the mentioned doc how to build the target binder-specific artifact which will be compatible with SCDF environment.

Now about the questions:

To poll sub-directories for the same file pattern, you need to configure a `RecursiveDirectoryScanner` on the `Files.inboundAdapter()`:

```
/**
 * Specify a custom scanner.
 * @param scanner the scanner.
 * @return the spec.
 * @see FileReadingMessageSource#setScanner(DirectoryScanner)
 */
public FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec scanner(DirectoryScanner scanner) {
```

Note that all the `filters` must be configured on this `DirectoryScanner` instead.
There is going to be a warning otherwise:

```
    // Check that the filter and locker options are _NOT_ set if an external scanner has been set.
    // The external scanner is responsible for the filter and locker options in that case.
    Assert.state(!(this.scannerExplicitlySet && (this.filter != null || this.locker != null)),
            () -> "When using an external scanner the 'filter' and 'locker' options should not be used. " +
                    "Instead, set these options on the external DirectoryScanner: " + this.scanner);
```

To keep track of the files, it is better to consider to have a `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` based on the external persistence store for the `ConcurrentMetadataStore` implementation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/#metadata-store. This must be used instead of that `preventDuplicates()`, because `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` ensure *only once* logic for us as well.

Deleting file after sending might not be a case, since you may just send `File` as is and it is has to be available on the other side.

Also, you can add a `ChannelInterceptor` into the `source.output()` and implement its `postSend()` to perform `((File) message.getPayload()).delete()`, which is going to happen when the message has been successfully sent to the binder destination.

Comment: Hi Artem
This is great information and so quick!

I'll try these out and update in this ticket.

Thank You!

Comment: Hi Artem
I got the recursive directory watch and delete/move post send working based on your suggestions.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: One thing I couldn't surpass is to let scanner disregard the directory itself. The file polling under subdirectories is fine. But, the directory itself is attempted to be sent as a message. 

preSend interceptor doesn't help as the below exception is being raised even before preSend(). 
The exception is obvious, but I'm unable to prevent attempting transformation on the directory

failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: c:\temp\Inbound\Temp

Comment: Well, just don't allow filters to pass directory instances. I see you use there `setAlwaysAcceptDirectories`. So, that is exactly what you get downstream: you allow to send dirs, and you get them in messages in your flow. Not a surprise.

Comment: setAlwaysAcceptDirectory irresepective of being set as true or false, directories are not ignored.

Is it possible that the condition here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/filters/AbstractSimplePatternFileListFilter.java#L49 is supposed to be && instead of || 

  return alwaysAccept(file) && (file != null && this.matcher.match(this.path, this.getFilename(file)));

Comment: Wait. Do you really need to send directories downstream? I don't talk only about the root one. All the nested dirs are going to be sent anyway. Not sure why you worry about the logic in the filter, allow to apply dirs and express a concern that dirs are sent downstream. And that all you do at the same time. You may extra filter though to exclude a root dir if that is only an issue...

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need sub-directories to be scanned for all files based on the simple or regex pattern and files be sent. 

But, directory types are required to be discarded for send. 

The below is the result of attempting to send directory, by name 'Temp1', which I want to avoid:

Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failed to transform File Message; nested exception is java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: c:\temp\Inbound\Temp1, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=c:\temp\Inbound\Temp1, headers={file_originalFile=c:\temp\Inbound\Temp1

Comment: Right. That's why I don't understand why do you use `setAlwaysAcceptDirectories(true)`? Why just don't rely on the default `false` one and be happy with all the files only from the whole tree skipping directories altogether?

Comment: The behavior is not as expected with 'false' value for alwaysAcceptDirectories. It is not skipping directories. I tried 'true' value which produces the same behavior of file access exception

Comment: Try to use `ChainFileListFilter` instead of `CompositeFileListFilter`, but still it isn't clear why would one set `alwaysAcceptDirectories` to true if he is not interested in dirs...

Comment: The directory files are not skipped with using ChainFileListFilter instead of CompositeFileListFilter.

The flag alwaysAcceptDirectories is set to false.
Still encountering exception such as this:
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)

Answer (score 0):

```
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
@Import(TriggerConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({FileSourceProperties.class, FileConsumerProperties.class,
    TriggerPropertiesMaxMessagesDefaultUnlimited.class})
public class FileSourceConfiguration {


@Autowired
@Qualifier("defaultPoller")
PollerMetadata defaultPoller;
@Autowired
Source source;
@Autowired
private FileSourceProperties properties;
@Autowired
private FileConsumerProperties fileConsumerProperties;

private Boolean alwaysAcceptDirectories = false;
private Boolean deletePostSend;
private Boolean movePostSend;
private String movePostSendSuffix;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileSourceFlow() {
    FileInboundChannelAdapterSpec messageSourceSpec = Files.inboundAdapter(new File(this.properties.getDirectory()));

    RecursiveDirectoryScanner recursiveDirectoryScanner = new RecursiveDirectoryScanner();
    messageSourceSpec.scanner(recursiveDirectoryScanner);
    FileVisitOption[] fileVisitOption = new FileVisitOption[1];
    recursiveDirectoryScanner.setFilter(initializeFileListFilter());

    initializePostSendAction();

    IntegrationFlowBuilder flowBuilder = IntegrationFlows
            .from(messageSourceSpec,
                    new Consumer<SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec>() {

                        @Override
                        public void accept(SourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec) {
                            sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec
                                    .poller(defaultPoller);
                        }

                    });

    ChannelInterceptor channelInterceptor = new ChannelInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {
            if (sent) {
                File fileOriginalFile = (File) message.getHeaders().get("file_originalFile");
                if (fileOriginalFile != null) {
                    if (movePostSend) {
                        fileOriginalFile.renameTo(new File(fileOriginalFile + movePostSendSuffix));
                    } else if (deletePostSend) {
                        fileOriginalFile.delete();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Override more interceptor methods to capture some logs here
    };
    MessageChannel messageChannel = source.output();
    ((DirectChannel) messageChannel).addInterceptor(channelInterceptor);
    return FileUtils.enhanceFlowForReadingMode(flowBuilder, this.fileConsumerProperties)
            .channel(messageChannel)
            .get();
}

private void initializePostSendAction() {
    deletePostSend = this.properties.isDeletePostSend();
    movePostSend = this.properties.isMovePostSend();
    movePostSendSuffix = this.properties.getMovePostSendSuffix();

    if (deletePostSend && movePostSend) {
        String errorMessage = "The 'delete-file-post-send' and 'move-file-post-send' attributes are mutually exclusive";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
    }

    if (movePostSend && (movePostSendSuffix == null || movePostSendSuffix.trim().length() == 0)) {
        String errorMessage = "The 'move-post-send-suffix' is required when 'move-file-post-send' is set to true.";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
    }

    //Add additional validation to ensure the user didn't configure a file move that will result in cyclic processing of file
}

private FileListFilter<File> initializeFileListFilter() {

    final List<FileListFilter<File>> filtersNeeded = new ArrayList<FileListFilter<File>>();

    if (this.properties.getFilenamePattern() != null && this.properties.getFilenameRegex() != null) {
        String errorMessage = "The 'filename-pattern' and 'filename-regex' attributes are mutually exclusive.";
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
    }

    if (StringUtils.hasText(this.properties.getFilenamePattern())) {
        SimplePatternFileListFilter patternFilter = new SimplePatternFileListFilter(this.properties.getFilenamePattern());
        if (this.alwaysAcceptDirectories != null) {
            patternFilter.setAlwaysAcceptDirectories(this.alwaysAcceptDirectories);
        }
        filtersNeeded.add(patternFilter);
    } else if (this.properties.getFilenameRegex() != null) {
        RegexPatternFileListFilter regexFilter = new RegexPatternFileListFilter(this.properties.getFilenameRegex());
        if (this.alwaysAcceptDirectories != null) {
            regexFilter.setAlwaysAcceptDirectories(this.alwaysAcceptDirectories);
        }
        filtersNeeded.add(regexFilter);
    }

    FileListFilter<File> createdFilter = null;

    if (!Boolean.FALSE.equals(this.properties.isIgnoreHiddenFiles())) {
        filtersNeeded.add(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter());
    }

    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(this.properties.isPreventDuplicates())) {
        filtersNeeded.add(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
    }

    if (filtersNeeded.size() == 1) {
        createdFilter = filtersNeeded.get(0);
    } else {
        createdFilter = new CompositeFileListFilter<File>(filtersNeeded);
    }

    return createdFilter;
}
```

}